# Running privoxy with C# ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, .net, process

When I try to run privoxy, I keep getting this error `can't check configuration file 'config.txt: error number 0'`

```
static void StartPrivoxy(Process p)
{
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy\privoxy.exe");
    p.Start();
}
```

The directory should be correct.  I can run it from command prompt at C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy\ and I can double click it.  The config is in the same directory.

I used the same code to run other programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the working directory for the process?

```
    static void StartPrivoxy(Process p)
    {
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy\privoxy.exe");
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy\";
        p.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Hmm I should've did that.  I thought it did run from that directory.

Comment: Even better use define the executable location as "privAppLoc" then p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(privAppLoc);
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(privAppLoc);